# Sharepoint DOM input type

Tags: javascript, dom, sharepoint

I am trying to create a dynamic webform on SharePoint and I am having an issue when trying to set the types of the elements with JavaScript and DOM.

I tried setting other types such as file, numeric, but they throw the same error (Member Not Found)

```
objElement = document.createElement("div");
objAttribute = document.createAttribute("class");
objAttribute.value = "container";
objElement.setAttributeNode(objAttribute);
objElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Client Name"));
objInput = document.createElement("input");
objAttribute = document.createAttribute("style");
objAttribute.value = "margin-left:70px;padding-left:10px;height:25px;border-color:RGB(184, 184, 184)";
objInput.setAttributeNode(objAttribute);
objAttribute = document.createAttribute("type");
objAttribute.value = "text";
objInput.setAttributeNode(objAttribute);
```

Error only occurs when setting the type attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Create the input textbox control like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to create a Text Field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
  x.setAttribute("type", "text");
  x.setAttribute("value", "Hello World!");
  document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```